# GLSurfaceView.Renderer doesn't work

Tags: android, opengl-es, renderer, glsurfaceview

I'm developing a openGL game in which I have a glSurfaceView. In it, I create a Renderer and I set it with setRenderer(r);.

The problem is that it is not working. His methods aren't called: onSurfaceCreated, onSurfaceChanged, onDrawFrame... anything works.

What could it be? In my GLSurfaceView, the method surfaceCreated is called. But the renderer one not...

Thanks